# Mongodb aggregation that returns all documents where $lookup foreign doc DOESN'T exist

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm working with a CMS system right now where if pages are deleted the associated content isn't. In the case of one of my clients this has become burdensome, as we now have millions of content docs accumulated over time, and it's making it prohibitive to do daily functions, like restoring dbs, backing up dbs, etc.

Consider this structure:

Page document:

```
{
  _id: pageId,
  contentDocumentId: someContentDocId
}
```

Content document:

```
{
  _id: someContentDocId,
  page_id: pageId,
  content: [someContent, ...etc]
}
```

Is there a way to craft a MongoDB aggregation where we aggregate Content docs based on checking `page_id`, and if our check for `page_id` returns null, then we aggregate that doc? It's not something as simple as foreignField in a $lookup being set to null, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
db.content.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "pages",
      "localField": "page_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "pages"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "pages_length": {
        "$size": "$pages"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "pages_length": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "pages",
      "pages_length"
    ]
  }
])
```

We create an aggregation from the `content` collection and do a normal `$loopup` with the `pages` collection. When no matching page is found, the array `pages` will be `[]` so we just filter every document where the array is empty.

You can't use `$size` inside `$match` to filter array lengths, so we need to create a temporary field `pages_length` to store the length of the array.

In the end we remove the temporary fields with `$unset`.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fR6cZBBTvrX)